# Resolve from file instead of typings in Lerna monorepo with yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, lerna

I'm using Lerna monorepo with Yarn workspaces. In one of packages i have few simple functions and when I'm importing them in another package, VSCode always resolves them from `build` directory, so when i make changes I have to rebuild and reload window to see them. Also when i `Go to definition` my IDE redirects me to `*.d.ts` file instead of function definition.

My goal is to make my IDE see imports from definition instead of typings inside build directory.

I already tried path aliases but I have doubts if this is even ok practice while using lerna with yarn workspaces. Another problem is that path leads me to root direction of package causing error and it builds whole file instead of only test function:

`File '.../packages/types/src/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '.../packages/api/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

```
// packages/api/src/index.ts
import { test } from '@project/types';

// packages/types/src/index.ts
export const test = () => {
  return 42;
};
```

Is it possible to do without path aliases?

Comment: See [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html)

Comment: You are my hero, I tried that too but with path aliases that were giving me the error above, without them everything works perfectly. Thank you